# minimum image size for tesseract

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to use `tesseract` to recognize characters from an Image. This image is created by grabbing characters from another image and putting them in a row in a new image. The problem is when I supply this image to `tesseract` it doesn't show anything in the output but when I paste this image in another image with size `640 x 480` I get correct results. what is the reason for this behavior? how can I fix this? what am I missing here?

Image without output:
[image]

Image with correct output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use  --psm 6   parameter for tesseract